# how to fix duplicate content inside different tabs in angular material 6?

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
    <form [formGroup]="cashflowForm">
          <mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selected.value" (selectedIndexChange)="selected.setValue($event)">
            <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tab; let index = index" [label]="tab">
              <mat-tab-group>
                <mat-tab *ngFor="let tabz of tabs; let i=index " [label]="tabz.Name">
                  <div formArrayName="itemRows" *ngFor="let item of cashflowForm.get('itemRows').controls">
                    <div [formGroupName]="0">
                      <table>
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>
                              Estimated Cash Flows Date
                            </th>
                            <th>
                              Principle Amount
                            </th>
                            <th>
                              Interest Amount
                            </th>
                            <th>
                              Total
                            </th>
                            <th>
                              PV of Estimated Cash Flows
                            </th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <input type="text" name="ECFDate" formControlName="ECFDate" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              <input type="text" name="principalFCValue" formControlName="principalFCValue" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              <input type="text" name="intrestCRecovery" formControlName="intrestCRecovery" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              <input type="text" name="cashflowtotal" formControlName="cashflowtotal" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              <input type="text" name="PVEstablishCash" formControlName="PVEstablishCash" />
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                      <table>
                        <tr>
                          <td> <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="addNewTab(tabz.id)">Add Row</a></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </mat-tab>
              </mat-tab-group>
            </mat-tab>
          </mat-tab-group>
        </form>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>





    

    
        import { Component } from '@angular/core';
        import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
    
        @Component({
          selector: 'app-root',
          templateUrl: './app.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
        })
        export class AppComponent {
          title = 'angularMaterialTask';
          public cashflowForm: FormGroup;
          tab = ['First', 'Second'];
          tabs = ['Inside First']
          selected = new FormControl(0);
          constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}
          ngOnInit(){
             this.cashflowForm = this.fb.group({
               itemRows: this.fb.array([this.addItemRows()])
             });
          }
          addItemRows(): FormGroup{
            return this.fb.group({
              ECFDate: [''],
              principalFCValue: ['', Validators.required],
              intrestCRecovery: ['', Validators.required],
              cashflowtotal:    [''],
              PVEstablishCash: ['', Validators.required]
            });
          }
    
    
          addNewTab(){
              (<FormArray>this.cashflowForm.get('itemRows')).push(this.addItemRows());
    
          }
          removeTab(index: number) {
            this.tab.splice(index, 1);
          }
        }
```

I have a form with two main tabs First and Second. I would like to add some controls within each tab, but for each tab content may or may not be same.
How to add dynamic content for each tab.

Right now code is working. But it is adding controls to both the tabs. When I click AddRow button it adds the controls, but it is reflecting across all the tabs (first and second).

following image depicts the same.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgGrt.png)

Comment: addNewTab(){
      (<FormArray>this.cashflowForm.get('itemRows')).push(this.addItemRows());

  }

Comment: Add your html and compoent.ts code here!

Comment: above is the function used to add controls

Comment: code has been added

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to have dynamic forms, but, if you take a look onto your `HTML` template, you are:

1. using 2 times an `*ngFor` to iterate static arrays (your `addNewTab` doesn't change the properties you're using to iterate). This is the root cause of the duplication.
2. your `tab` and `tabs` arrays are static and are not the real source of the dynamic tabs. On remove action you remove and index of it, but on add you're not adding a new index to these arrays.
3. `addTab` adds a new `FormGroup` to the `FormArray`, but the form fields rendered are not receiving the right form control.

Here are some guidelines you could follow to implement it.

1. Define the `FormArray` of [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) and use its items to iterate in the template and render.
2. To render the form controls, pass the [`formControl`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlDirective) property of the current form `item` instead of the `formControlName`, this way you're assigning the inputs to the equivalent form object controls and will be able to retrieve the values later.

Reading the [Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) guide would be interesting for you as well.